# Cell is not hiding properly on iPad?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I want to hide/remove a row when a condition is met.

I made some research and I found that you can do this by returning 0 for the cell Height.

this works great on the iPhone, but not for the iPad.

please advice.

Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image]

when its not hidden it looks like this:

[image]

my code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([indexPath section]==2 && [indexPath row]==0 && [self hasNoContact]) {
        return 0;
    }
  return 44;
}
```

`hasNoContact` is a bool I use to determine if it should be hidden.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Anonymous please read my question bro

Comment: Whatever logic you have in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` to return 0, just put it in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to return an empty cell as well.

Comment: @Stonz2 they are statics cell thats the thing

Comment: Static or dynamic doesn't make a difference

Comment: While it doesnt, it requires me to implement the method and return each possible cell on my tableview. I wish there is an easier way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it like [@Stonz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616071/cell-is-not-hiding-properly-on-ipad/22617948#comment34438571_22616071) suggested in the comment, return an empty cell.

> it requires me to implement the method and return each possible cell on my tableview. I wish there is an easier way

Well, you mention that they are static, you dont have to return each possible cell, you can get it from `super`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([indexPath section]==2 && [indexPath row]==0 && [self hasNoContact]) {
        return [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
    }
    return [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```